# What's mean that Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider?

Tags: spring

I compiling springframework project using with springframework-3.0.1. But, I got error messages, "Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider",

What is it? help me,

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually have a ValidationProvider on your class path?

Try adding the reference implementation Hibernate Validator 4 to your class path.